# Advantages and disadvantages of the program Code. Documentation on features and differences from others

Tags: code

Hello respected community and developers. First, I want to express my gratitude for your work.
I am interested in the program for text and code editing - Code.
I would like to ask about its differences from others, what are its advantages and disadvantages?
Where can I read documentation about the program?
Is there telemetry in the program?
Would be a good choice if I want to completely switch to writing code and scripts in it?
Will there be any problems when installing this program in other distributions?
Thank you very much!

Comment: HI there! Nice to see you interested in Code's features :D But i think features are better discussed in Code's github repo https://github.com/elementary/code/issues, or in the elementary OS subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/new/

Comment: Just run it and see, it's rather simple. From my side, I suggest you to uninstall it, and get Visual Studio Code.

Comment: To answer the simplest question though: there's no telemetry. No built-in app for elementary OS has any sort of telemetry or analytics to collect your data.